# How to update <select> options with AngularJs on click

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following html code

```
<select name="Gender" class="form-control">
    <option value="m">Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
</select>
```

I want to change the select option on click with *AngularJs*.
I've tried almost everything, and I realize that the problem occurs when the click event is called, if there is no click event it works fine

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-click="setGender()">Set</div>
   <select name="Gender" class="form-control">
        <option value="m" ng-selected="{{GenderInfo.Gender =='m'}}">Male</option>
        <option value="f" ng-selected="{{GenderInfo.Gender =='f'}}">Female</option>
   </select>
</body>
```

**AngularJs:**

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.setGender = function(){
        $scope.GenderInfo = {
            Gender: 'f'
        }
    }
}
```

**JsFiddle:**
 http://jsfiddle.net/dCFd2/231/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need curly braces inside `ng-selected`:

```
<option value="m" ng-selected="GenderInfo.Gender =='m'">Male</option>
<option value="f" ng-selected="GenderInfo.Gender =='f'">Female</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like so:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-click="setGender()">Set</div>
   <select name="Gender" class="form-control">
        <option value="m" ng-selected="GenderInfo.Gender =='m'">Male</option>
        <option value="f" ng-selected="GenderInfo.Gender =='f'">Female</option>
   </select>
</body>
```

the `ngSelected` doesn't need {{}} because it evaluates the expression given.

Hope this helped. I've tested it with your jsFiddle and it seem to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

See my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/kiyanov/dCFd2/239/) with ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="GenderInfo" name="Gender" class="form-control" ng-options="g.value as g.title for g in gender">
```

Javascript:

```
 $scope.gender = [
            {value:'m',title:'Male'}, 
            {value:'f',title:'Female'}
            ];
        $scope.GenderInfo = $scope.gender[0].value;//Set Default gender
```

Comment: this is the right answer when you have a pre selected option and can be assumed as the right way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-options` See [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rnq87dhq/2/)

```
   <select ng-init="model.Gender = genders[0].Key" name="Gender" class="form-control" ng-model="model.Gender" ng-options="g.Key as g.Gender for g in genders">
```